# Anaconda and OpenCV using old version

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, anaconda

I am trying to download the latest version of OpenCV using anaconda, but Anaconda only has version 3.1.0. I ended up installing it with pip, but can someone explain why anaconda does not have 3.2.0 version of OpenCV. Also, I am using Python 2.7.

Thanks

Comment: There is no company that creates the Anaconda OpenCV installers, it's just groups of people. And they haven't gotten around to building one for 3.2 yet. You don't have to use the Anaconda installer, you can build it from source.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is there any way to bring this to their attention?

Comment: Whose attention?

Comment: The Anaconda maintainers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda is maintained by Continuum so it seems like they have not had a chance to update to the newer version of OpenCV. I will try to see if I can bring it to their attention.